# Apache RewriteRule without trailing slash(/)

Tags: url, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to redirect URLs with .htaccess like these:

```
example.io/foo => example.io/~user/foo
example.io/foo/ => example.io/~user/foo/
```

and I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.io) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /~user/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I access to `example.io/foo/`, it responses `[200]` and browser displays `example.io/foo/`,

but when accessing to `example.io/foo`, responses `[301]` and displays `example.io/~user/foo`.

I want the browser display `example.io/foo` (without slash) , when I access to `example.io/foo`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

```
example.io/foo => example.io/~user/foo
example.io/foo/ => example.io/~user/foo/
```

you should do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~user/$1 [L]
```